# Cannot log in to StackOverflow Careers

Tags: support, status-norepro, jobs, login, stack-exchange-openid

I know there are duplicates around but I get a weird case here.

I have received a message from StackOverflow Careers but when I try to login using StackExchange OpenID, I get the following:

[image]

Alternatively, when I try to login to Careers using my email address/password, I get the following message:

> Ah! We see that you have logged in before using an OpenID associated
>   with that email address.
>
> Please click one of the buttons to the left which corresponds to your
>   email or OpenID provider.
>
> «««

Please help! I am perfectly logged in on StackOverflow. Why doesn't Careers pick up the same token and authorize me to view my profile like other StackExchange sites?

Comment: This could be related to a hiccup we had earlier on the network. Can you still not login?

Comment: Could it be this: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/567673340358586369

Comment: Thanks. I have just checked now and I have successfully logged in (after so many retries).

Comment: @rla what happened in there? No juicy details?

Comment: @ShadowWizard oh well, it's definitely related to our network hiccup yesterday (postmortem: https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/111378728704/outage-postmortem-february-17-2015). Guess I'll just change it to no-repro.

Comment: @rla4 but [it still happens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269900/ah-we-see-that-you-have-logged-in-before-using-an-openid-associated-with-that). Any chance to look into it now? :)